# Does one still need to use -fPIC when compiling with GCC?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

On gcc target machines, when one wanted to compile a shared library, one would need to specify -fpic or -fPIC to get things to work correcly. This is because by default absolute addressing was used, which is suitable for executable that have full control of their own address space, but not shared libraries, which could be loaded anywhere in an executable's address space.

However modern kernels are now implementing address space randomization and many modern architectures support PC relative addressing. This all seems to make the absolute addressing either unusable (address space randomization) or unneeded (PC relative addressing).

I have also noticed that clang does not have an -fPIC option which makes me think that it is no longer necessary.

So is -fPIC now redundant or does one need to generate separate .o files, one for static library use, and one for shared library use?

Answer (score 7):

You still need to compile with -fPIC. The problem isn't solvable with pc-relative addressing. The problem is how you resolve external symbols. In a dynamically linked program the resolution follows different rules and especially with adress space randomization it can't be resolved during link time.

And clang does have the -fPIC flag just like gcc.

```
$ cat > foo.c
void foo(void);
void bar(void) { foo(); }
$ gcc -S foo.c && grep call.*foo foo.s
    call    foo
$ gcc -fPIC -S foo.c && grep call.*foo foo.s
    call    foo@PLT
$ clang -S foo.c && grep call.*foo foo.s
    callq   foo
$ clang -fPIC -S foo.c && grep call.*foo foo.s
    callq   foo@PLT
$
```

Comment: @doron I think it is (but maybe wasn't back in 2013): https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#target-independent-compilation-options

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the target.  Some targets (like x86_64) are position independent by default, sp `-fpic` is a noop and has no effect on the generated code.  So in those cases you can omit it and nothing changes.  Other targets (like x86 32-bit) are not position independent by default, so on those machines, if you omit `-fpic` for the executable, it will disable ASLR for that image file (but not for shared libraries it uses).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you: in many cases the -fpic/-fPIC options are almost redundant, I do however use them to ensure:

- portability (never sure what particular OS/kernel will be available)
- backwards compatibility: with those options it ensures the behaviour you want on older kernels
- habit - Hard things to break :)
- compliance with older codebases that may require it

Answer (score 0):

You never needed to generate separate `.o` files.  Always specify the compiler options to generate portable code (typically `-fPIC`).

On some systems, the compiler may be configured to force this option on, or set it by default.  But it doesn't hurt to specify it anyway.

Note: One hopes that where PC-relative addressing is supported *and performs well*, that `-fPIC` uses that mode rather than dedicating an extra register.

Comment: PIC code is slower in most cases because the extra jump through the PLT requires an extra indirection on many function calls. It's a good idea to build static libraries without PIC.

Comment: @Art: It may be slower, but not by much.  And I disagree that it's useful to build static libraries without.  Static libraries aren't only linked into executables, but also into shared libraries.  And, as the question mentioned, with ASLR executables also need to be position independent.  So the safest thing is to always specify `-fPIC`.

Comment: @Art The issue on an Intel isn't the function calls or jumps (which are all PC relative anyway), but accessing global data.  (On other processors, the issues will be different.)

Comment: If you're linking static libraries into dynamic libraries you should also build a pic version of the static library. Or preferably a partially linked PIC object file (which is what I do in a build system at work). Systems I've seen that actually have PIE (I guess that's what you mean by aslr executables) have defaulted the compiler to always generate PIC and you can't generate non-PIC code, so that's not a problem.

Comment: @JamesKanze You can't have a pc-relative function call when you don't know what offset your function will be in relation to the function you're calling which is a problem while dynamically linking. This is why in PIC mode, all compilers I know of will generate a PLT call. When building without PIC, you can avoid the PLT call which is one less indirection.

Comment: You do know the relative offset if in the same segment, and if different segments you don't know the offset, whether PIC or not.

Comment: Who uses segments? I thought even windows uses a flat address space today. Especially since long mode doesn't even allow for segmentation (other than the fs and gs registers which are often used for thread local storage and completely unrelated to this). Or did you mean something else with segments?

Comment: Segment or section, terminology varies by platform. .bss .ibss .text etc. These days segments don't affect virtual addresses, but page protection.

Comment: @BenVoigt Right. You do know the pc offset within the same text section. BUT. When compiling a PIC object with function calls between compilation units the compiler doesn't know if the function call will end up to be within the same library/section or if it will be to some other library/section, so in PIC mode it will always generate a PLT call. Unless you use visibility attributes in gcc (supported in clang too), you still get the overhead of the PLT call even though it could have been resolved as a pc-relative call.

Comment: @Art The Intel processor doesn't have any non-PC relative jumps or calls, except between segments (and both Linux and Windows put everything into a single segment).  The linker has to fix up the PC relative addresses.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Or use an absolute offset from the base of the single flat-memory segment... as must surely be done for function pointers and virtual calls.

Comment: @BenVoigt Indirect calls use an absolute address, so function pointers and virtual calls work.  All of the linkers I've seen patch the PC relative address; the linker knows the absolute address which needs patching, and the absolute target address, so it can calculate the difference and insert it.

Comment: @JamesKanze: And does the loader do the same, when patching cross-module calls?

Comment: Since I can't fit what I mean in this comment, see here: https://gist.github.com/art4711/8008821

Comment: @Art: Nice demonstration.  Do optimization flags have any effect on that?

Comment: @BenVoigt It should.  There shouldn't be any difference between dynamic linking and static linking.  All of the alternatives have a negative impact on performance.

Comment: @BenVoigt No. They can't have an effect on that. Because people have started depending on this behavior for legitimate use. For example if you do a LD_PRELOAD with a shared library with your own alternative implementation of malloc the functions in libc that call malloc will call malloc from your preloaded object and not the one in libc.

Answer (score 0):

`gcc` targets a lot of platforms and architectures, and not all of them supports natively PIC like the x86 architecture does. In some cases, creating PIC means additional overhead, which may be undesired, and wether you want or need this is depending on your project and the platform you are targeting,.